# Замена / синонимизация метки [sublime]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

На многие вопросы, связанные с редактором Sublime Text, пользователями вешается метка [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime), в то время как существует более корректная метка [sublimetext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext). Некоторые пользователи указывают обе, некоторые одну из двух, когда по сути обе метки обозначают одну и ту же область - вопрос о редакторе Sublime Text. Синонимом [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime) и [sublimetext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) на данный момент не связаны.

Если брать в пример EN SO, то метки [sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime) там и вовсе нет, зато есть sublimetext, sublimetext2, sublimetext3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime) это всегда о редакторе Sublime Text, то не вижу смысла удалять метку. Это как раз тот случай, когда ее надо синонимизировать (не удалить и не заменить).

Основная метка:

- [sublime-text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text)

Синонимы:

- [sublimetext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext)
- [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime)

---

Поскольку этот вариант получил поддержку, я только что произвел объединение меток. При этом произведена автоматическая замена меток на вопросах, перенастроены избранные метки и подписки, созданы синонимы.

Если интересно, это выглядит вот так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне так не кажется. Слово `sublime` не достаточно полно отражает название продукта, просто является часто используемым сокращением в быту. Такую же проблему я заметил с тегами [tag:idea] и [tag:intellij-idea] - действительно ли слово `idea` подразумевает соотв. IDE, если начинать думать о теге вне контекста.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: ну и с чем вы спорите-то? sublime и sublimetext станут синонимами, а  sublime-text — основной меткой.

Comment: Я наверное затронул чуть более глобальный вопрос - стоит ли использовать популярные сокращения в качестве синонимов. В данном случае при создании вопроса и вводе `sublime` автокомплит предложит вариант `sublimetext`, выглядит это и правда больше как сокращение, чем синоним. Синоним я вижу отличным в написании, например: `cordova` vs `phonegap`.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: вы знаете, как работают синонимы меток? )

Comment: Только что хотел написать, что только интуитивно догадываюсь) Мной двигала идея "меньше лучше чем больше".

Comment: Пока что [tag:sublime] на сайте употреблялась только в отношении Sublime Text, и маловероятно, что в ближайшее время (пара лет) будут разночтения.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: там суть в том, что все метки считаются одной, и при редактировании вопроса второстепенные заменяются на основную. Так что популярные сокращения как раз удобно использовать в качестве синонимов. Например, к c++ синонимизированы cpp и даже c++ с русской «с». )

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: что касается idea — тоже стоит синонимизировать.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: я выложил иллюстрацию того, как происходит объединение меток руками модератора (это немного больше, чем стандартный механизм). Возможно, вам будет интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало намного удобнее.

Answer (score 6):

Метка [sublimetext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) мне лично не нравится своим названием. Предлагаю заменить (в значении "добавить основной синоним") на [sublime-text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text) (в [кебаб-кейсе](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles)), потому что:

- С отдельными словами метку проще опознать визуально
- На [официальном сайте редактора](http://www.sublimetext.com/) "Sublime Text" пишется раздельно
- Уже есть [sublime-text-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text-3) в таком же стиле, и есть 8 отмеченных ею вопросов

Comment: шашлык-кейс! =)

Comment: А почему заменить, а не синонимизировать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да серьёзных причин нет, я просто слабо знаком с техпроцессом :) Синонимизация сойдёт, а в вашем ответе мои пожелания учтены.

Comment: а я полностью согласен, что cabob-case лучше