# Синонимизация меток idea и intellij-idea

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Чтобы обозначить то, что вопрос затрагивает IDE *IntelliJ Idea*, пользователи используют метки [idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea) и/или [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea). На данный момент они не связаны синонимом. Сама метка [idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea) используется только в вопросах о вышеупомянутом IDE и никакого другого значения пока не несет.

На EN SO существует только метка [intellij-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea), метка [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea) отсутствует и не является синонимом к [intellij-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea).

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2210/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-sublime) был по поводу меток [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime) и [sublime-text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text), где было принято решение провести их синонимизацию, т.к. метка [sublime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime) нигде, кроме как для обозначения редактора, не используется. Данную ситуацию считаю практически идентичной.

Предложение:

- сделать [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) основной меткой
- сделать [idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea) синонимом метки [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea)

Comment: Завершено, можете принимать ответ )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проголосовать за синонимизацию можно на странице **синонимов** метки [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/intellij-idea/synonyms

UPD:

Прошла неделя, за синоним хоть кто-то проголосовал, так что я решил провести объединение меток.

[idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idea) синонимизирована к [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) и заменена на неё во всех вопросах, где использовалась.

Для любителей читать логи:

```
updating post history, 22 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 68 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 57 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [intellij-idea] and [idea] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym idea -> intellij-idea was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```